# I want to get row numbers of all rows in a dataframe where an element in a column contains an element in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a character vector which looks something like this

```
Categories = sample(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 5), sep=''))
Categories
[1] "d-" "e-" "c-" "a-" "b-"
```

I have a dataframe df which looks like:

```
df = data.frame(name = c(1:10), cat = paste(c(letters[1:10]), "-1", sep = ""))
df
    name cat
1     1   a-1
2     2   b-1
3     3   c-1
4     4   d-1
5     5   e-1
6     6   f-1
7     7   g-1
8     8   h-1
9     9   i-1
10   10   j-1
```

I want to get row numbers in df in the order in which the elements of Categories are contained in the column "cat" in df. So, I want to get

```
dfRowNumbers
[1] 4,5,3,1,2
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most directly, you can use `charmatch`.

```
charmatch(vec, df$cat)
[1] 4 5 3 1 2
```

---

or return a named vector with `grep` and `sapply`.

```
sapply(Categories, grep, df$cat, fixed=TRUE)
d- e- c- a- b- 
 4  5  3  1  2
```

---

For a little semantic sugar, build your own function with `Vectorize`:

```
vecGrep <- Vectorize(grep, vectorize.args="pattern")
```

Then use it to return a named vector

```
vecGrep(Categories, df$cat, fixed=TRUE)
d- e- c- a- b- 
 4  5  3  1  2
```

---

**data**

```
vec <- c("d-", "e-", "c-", "a-", "b-")
df = data.frame(name = c(1:10), cat = paste(c(letters[1:10]), "-1", sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `match` after removing the numeric substring of 'cat' column with `sub`

```
match(Categories, sub("\\d+$", "", df$cat))
#[1] 4 5 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which uses a for-loop over your categories-vector

```
rownums <- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(Categories)) {
  rownums[length(rownums) + 1] <- grep(Categories[i], df$cat)
}
```

The `grep()`-command returns the rownumbers in `df$cat` which contain `Categories[i]`. The result is saved in the `rownums`-vector.